# Basic Footer Positioning Issue

Tags: php, css, content-management-system

So hey guys. I'm new to the site, but have a problem concerning my footer image positioning. I'm sure it's basic for all of you, but I've tried several methods that I came across online, and had no luck. In the end, I decided to ask around.

My issue is this. The CMS I use ( http://www.animerelief.com/ ) and/or ( http://www.anime-static.com/ ) - if you scroll down to the bottom of any page, you'll see that (in a 1080x1920 resolution) the footer aligns with the text properly, and in the center of the footer area. My problem is, in any resolution under that, the footer moves, and ends up out of place with the website.

How do I go about maintaining a single position for the footer image and/or text/links in it?

Thanks for your help!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `min-width` to the body that it's equal to your holder width.

```
body { min-width: 1087px; }
```